# Unable to get data from http.get via Observable via ngOnInit in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, undefined

On my component init I'm getting data from the server

```
 import {Rules} from "../../interfaces/interfaces";
 rules: Rules
 ngOnInit() {
  this.tt = this.rulesService.getUserClientRules().subscribe(
   t => {
     console.log(t)
     console.log(t.clientRules.canAll)
     this.rules = t.clientRules
   },
   error => {
    console.log(error.error.message)
   }
  )
 }
```

My service code is

```
getUserClientRules(): Observable<Rules> {
return this.http.get<Rules>('/api/rules/getClientUserRules/')}

and I have interface like:

export interface Rules {
 clientRules: any
}
```

I'm getting response like this:

```
**{clientRules: {canAll: true, canSee: false}}**
```

How I can push this object into my rules object? I want to use it like **rules.canAll** or **rules.canSeeAll**...

*and when I try **console.log(this.rules)** I'm getting **undefined***

I need this strucrure rules **{ canAll: true, canSee: true }** I need to use it for the checks like ***ngIf="rules.canSee"**

Thank you for your responses!!!

Comment: Have you monitored the http traffic and have you confirmed that the data is successfully transported from the http server to the client?

Comment: yes. 
console.log(t.clientRules.canAll)  returning TRUE and console.log(t.clientRules) returns {canAll: true, canSee: false} but I need to push that in rules var

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement the interface should actually look like

```js
export interface Rules {
  canAll: boolean;
  canSee: boolean;
}
```

Then you could RxJS `map` operator to return the `clientRules` property from the HTTP call

Service

```js
getUserClientRules(): Observable<Rules> {
  return this.http.get<Rules>('/api/rules/getClientUserRules/').pipe(
    map(response => response['clientRules'])
  );
}
```

You could then assign the response directly to the `rules` variable in the component

Component

```js
rules: Rules

ngOnInit() {
  this.tt = this.rulesService.getUserClientRules().subscribe(
    t => {
      console.log(t);
      console.log(t.canAll);
      this.rules = t; // <-- the response is already the `clientRules` property
    },
    error => {
      console.log(error.error.message)
    }
  );
}
```

You could then use it in the template using the safe navigation operator `?.` to avoid unnecessary `undefined` errors.

Template

```html
<div *ngIf="rules?.canSee">
  User can see...
</div>
```

Comment: it's works. thank you! but again I can't console.log(this.rules) = undefined

Comment: @Павел: Variable `this.rules` is assigned asynchronously. So the `console.log(this.rules)` statement _should_ be inside the subscription.